# Flutter : Change the path of recorded video

Tags: android, flutter, video, camera, video-player

I have to record a video with a timer and stop the recording after few seconds.
When I click on stop button I am getting this error everytime. I have tested it on different real devices and emulator.

```
E/flutter ( 8026): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(INVALID_PATH, The platform "TargetPlatform.android" did not return a path while reporting success. The platform should always return a valid path or report an error.)
E/flutter ( 8026): #0      MethodChannelCamera.stopVideoRecording (package:camera_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_camera.dart:240:7)
E/flutter ( 8026): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8026): #1      CameraController.stopVideoRecording (package:camera/src/camera_controller.dart:524:20)
E/flutter ( 8026): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8026):
```

Is there a way to change the default path  `/data/user/0/package/cache/REC9113430186235591563.mp4` of recorded videos.
My code:

```
Future<XFile> _stopVideoRecording() async {
   
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      _changedButtonVisibility(true);
      XFile video = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
     // await GallerySaver.saveVideo(video.path); //for testing
      return video;
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting any path in video.path?

Comment: Yes I am getting the path data/user/0/package/cache/REC9113430186235591563.mp4

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chnage the default path then you can use the package below :

[path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

something like below :

```
 try {
       Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // to get directory path
      _changedButtonVisibility(true);
      XFile video = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
       final fileName = basename(video.path); // will return you the name of your file like REC9113430186235591563.mp4
       final filePath = "${path.path}/$fileName"; 
      await GallerySaver.saveVideo(filePath); //for testing
      return video;
    }
```

For basename you have to import this :

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```

Comment: I am already able to copy the file using GallerySaver, i dont want to save the file on cache on stop button taped but stopVideoRecording() is making file data/user/0/package/cache/ which throw invalid path

Comment: video.path path is cache path but path.path is directory path not cache one. Your error is because that you were passing cache path in saveVideo() right?

Comment: as soon as .stopVideoRecording(); has called , i got the error

Comment: controller.stopVideoRecording() function returns the recorded flie , this is the function of camera plugin

Comment: Can you share a reproducible code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617675/flutter-disposed-cameracontroller-buildpreview-was-called-on-a-disposed-cam